# Can't Debug Application-Level Add-in for Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin

This is the first time I am using  .NET to create an Application-level Add-in for Outlook. By using a tutorial I wrote down some code and it was successfully build, but I was unable to debug the code. While debugging an alert box displays saying:

> You cannot run or debug this project because the required version of the Microsoft application is not installed.

I am using **Visual Studio 2010** and **MS Office 2007**. In order to debug the code what shall I do? Can I make any change in code so that I can debug it.

here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
namespace OutlookAddIn1
{

    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
        event InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler NewInspector;


        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
            inspectors.NewInspector +=
            new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector); 
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
                {
                    mailItem.Subject = "This text was added by using code";
                    mailItem.Body = "This text was added by using code";
                }

            }
        }
        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is not your code - it is a misconfiguration of your project file and which MS Office version you have installed. See [related SO post regarding editing `DebugInfoExeName` in the `csproj` to match the proper Office version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284425/175679).

```
Office Version | Version Number
---------------+-----------------
    2007       |   12.0
    2010       |   14.0
    2013       |   15.0
    2016       |   16.0
```

For **MS Office 2007**, your project file `DebugInfoExeName` should be:

> DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\InstallRoot \Path#outlook.exe"

Comment: For MS Office 2016, the version number is "16.0".