# How to create Add-ins 2007 in visual studio 2012,

Tags: excel

I could not found Office 2007 project wizard in VS 2012 , only support for Office 2010. But , i want to create a 2007 Excel add-in so that use this addin on both 2007 office and 2010 office. 
Please give me any help to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12277023/293078) to the same question got a lot of upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The link that Doug Glancy addresses the following issue:
You have Visual Studio 2012 and Office 2007 installed on your development computer.

If you have Visual Studio 2012 and Office 2010 installed, and you want your Excel add-in to target Office 2007 as well then you don't have to do anything. An Excel 2010 add-in created with VS2012 will work with Excel 2007, Excel 2010, and Excel 2013.