# Is it possible to create an Excel Add-in for Excel 2007?

Tags: vsto, excel-2007, excel-interop, office-addins, excel-addins

The users here have Excel 2007. I want to create an add-in to react to a PivotTable being changed. In Visual Studio 2013, I created an Excel Add-in via New project > Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Office/SharePoint > Office Add-ins > Excel 2010 Add-in

To be a little more specific about my situation, I need to massage a pivot table after the user filters it in the .xlsx file (Excel 2007). I think the only way I can do this is via a VSTO add-in. I've got this:

```
namespace ExcelAddInForRptRunner
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet sh = this.Application.ActiveSheet;
            sh.PivotTableUpdate += new Excel.DocEvents_PivotTableUpdateEventHandler(sh_PivotTableUpdate);
        }

        void sh_PivotTableUpdate(Excel.PivotTable TargetPivotTable)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sh_PivotTableUpdate event fired");
        }
    }
}
```

When I right-click the project and select Debug > Start New Instance, I get "You cannot debug or run this project, because the required version of the Microsoft Office application is not installed." and "Unable to start debugging"

It's true that I don't have Excel 2010 installed, but I had hoped that the "Excel 2010 Add-in" project would also work for Excel 2007.

Is this err msg I'm seeing because the .DLL needs to be deployed somehow/way, or is it really because Excel 2010 is not installed, or what?

Comment: did you try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277023/how-can-i-create-a-vsto-office-2007-add-in-using-vs-2012

Comment: I had not seen it; thanks!